# Why does computing correlation between index levels vs. percentage changes yield completely different results?

Tags: equities, time-series, statistics, forecasting

I am examining the relationship between the S&P 500 and the Industrial Production Index. Computing the correlation between these these variables yield vastly different results if expressed in percentage changes as opposed to using the index approach (i.e. choosing an index year and multiplying the percentage changes).

Percentage changes
CORR (S&P500, IndustrialProduction) = -0.006460759

Index levels
CORR (S&P500, IndustrialProduction) = 0.890445169

How does this make sense?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/7378 explains it all

Comment: The index level correlation is not valid and should be disregarded. It is a so-called "spurious correlation" between two random walks. http://www.fsb.miamioh.edu/lij14/672_2014_s8.pdf

Comment: So it would be wrong to regress the index levels against each other using Vector Autoregression?

Comment: @DBE7 [That depends on whether the processes are cointegrated.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238090/why-are-my-var-models-working-better-with-nonstationary-data-than-stationary-dat?rq=1) If the two processes are both [integrated of order 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_integration) and [cointegrated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cointegration), then regressing one on the other can recover the cointegrating vector with super-consistent convergence. But if they're not cointegrated, you'll get a spurious result (if you mistakenly assume regular OLS assumptions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The linked to answer does explain it all, but in brief because one set are stationary processes and the others are not.

Correlation as a measures gives us the normalized degree of co-movement between process residuals, which assumes stationary processes.  With non-constant mean term (ie, non-stationary processes), there's no way to parse out and relate which portion of the movement is based on the drift and which is based on the residual.  Same goes for regressions (ie, you can't regress a price time series against a predictor variable; you need to use returns).